# how are distributive property rules in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

It is interesting for me how the haskell multiplies when there is a parentheses. For example:

5*(3 + 4)

3 + 4 = 7

5 * 7 = 35

i multiply this way

but i have a doubt that Haskell (ghci) does the same

5*3 + 5*4 = 35

are there any distributivity property rules or not ?

thanks for your attention

Comment: You mean any *distributive* property?

Comment: yes i am sorry you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer: no.

Moreover, there is no interest for a compiler to apply the distributivity rule in this direction: you'll have to perform 3 operations (two *, one +) instead of two.

Comment: i see why one multiply but i didnt get why two '+' operations??? i see only one 3 + 4 where is the second operation of '+'??? ( i am new to haskell sorry if my questions are silly)

Comment: I think he means two *, one +.

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell, `5*(3 + 4)` is syntactic sugar of `(*) 5 ((+) 3 4)`, so I think the sum is performed before the product.